# The result obtained by mac's df-h command is why avail+used is nearly 200G less than size, and this is a relatively common phenomenon

Tags: mac

[image]

Avail+used is nearly 200G less than size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your disk looks like it is mounted several times in different places, judging by the fact that "avail" is 317Gib for every disk.

Mac APFS supports [space sharing](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/system-information/sysp560a2952/mac) across a disk so your "partitions" `disk1ls1`, `disk1ls2`, `disk1ls5`, `disk1ls6` all pull from the same space pool and you have to add all the "used" disk areas.

The "317" avail plus all the "used" areas (10 + 119 + 3 + 16) is approximately 465Gib which appears to be the total size of the disk.